# Changing envelope sender in a DocuSign Envelope that has already been sent

Tags: docusignapi

If a user who is a sender leaves the company, is there a way (as an admin) to re-assign all envelopes that were sent by the sender to someone else?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via the DS API, but it is possible in the WebApp. With that user shared you can highlight one or multiple envelopes and "Transfer Selected Ownership" to another user on the account. https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-transferring-your-envelopes-or-shared-envelopes